# OpenVPN error status: 2, and can't connect to internet while using

Tags: ubuntu, networking, openvpn

I recently installed openVPN and configured it with my client1.ovpn file:

```
client

dev tun

proto udp

remote 10.8.0.1 1194

resolv-retry infinite

nobind

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

key-direction 1

cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA256

comp-lzo

verb 3

script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

my server.conf file:

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key 

dh dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"

push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"

keepalive 10 120

tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret
key-direction 0

cipher AES-128-CBC   # AES
auth SHA256

comp-lzo

user nobody
group nogroup

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log

verb 3
```

When I do the command

```
sudo openvpn --config client1.ovpn
```

I get this error in the terminal:

```
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 OpenVPN 2.3.10 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL 
(OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, 
LZO 2.08
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Control Channel Authentication: tls-auth 
using INLINE static key file
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: 
Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992-
>212992]
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed 
because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 TLS: Initial packet from 
[AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194, sid=640d1419 b8d9a3ee
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los 
Angeles, O=Fort-Funston, OU=Community, CN=Fort-Funston CA, 
name=Server, emailAddress=fasching.ryan@gmail.com
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Validating certificate key usage
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 ++ Certificate has key usage  00a0, expects 
00a0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY KU OK
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Validating certificate extended key usage
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server 
Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY EKU OK
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=US, ST=CA, L=Los 
Angeles, O=Fort-Funston, OU=Community, CN=Ryan, name=Server, 
emailAddress=fasching.ryan@gmail.com
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Encrypt: Using 256 bit message 
hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' 
initialized with 128 bit key
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Data Channel Decrypt: Using 256 bit message 
hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, 2048 bit RSA
Sat Aug 12 21:57:10 2017 [Ryan] Peer Connection Initiated with 
[AF_INET]10.8.0.1:1194
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 SENT CONTROL [Ryan]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' 
(status=1)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 PUSH: Received control message: 
'PUSH_REPLY,redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp,dhcp-option DNS 
208.67.222.222,dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220,route 10.8.0.1,topology 
net30,ping 10,ping-restart 120,ifconfig 10.8.0.6 10.8.0.5'
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts 
modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ifconfig/up options 
modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 OPTIONS IMPORT: --ip-win32 and/or --dhcp-
option options modified
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 WARNING: potential conflict between --remote 
address [10.8.0.1] and --ifconfig address pair [10.8.0.6, 10.8.0.5] -- 
this is a warning only that is triggered when local/remote addresses 
exist within the same /24 subnet as --ifconfig endpoints. (silence 
this warning with --ifconfig-nowarn)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ROUTE_GATEWAY 10.15.65.1/255.255.255.0 
IFACE=wlp1s0 HWADDR=d0:57:7b:09:c7:c0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 TUN/TAP device tun1 opened
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt-
>did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip link set dev tun1 up mtu 1500
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip addr add dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 
peer 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.15.65.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.5
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 /sbin/ip route add 10.8.0.1/32 via 10.8.0.5
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 GID set to nogroup
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 UID set to nobody
Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

I also cannot connect to the internet while openvpn is in use in the terminal. It isn't until I hit crtl+c before I'm able to connect to the internet again.

After ctrl+c I get these errors as well:

```
^CSat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 event_wait : Interrupted system call 
(code=4)
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 10.8.0.1/32
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 0.0.0.0/1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip route del 128.0.0.0/1
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 ERROR: Linux route delete command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 /sbin/ip addr del dev tun1 local 10.8.0.6 
peer 10.8.0.5
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 Linux ip addr del failed: external program 
exited with error status: 2
Sat Aug 12 21:57:56 2017 SIGINT[hard,] received, process exiting
```

I have been trying to find an answer to this question a lot on google already with no luck. What is causing this error of " ERROR: Linux route add command failed: 
external program exited with error status: 2" as well as being able to connect to the internet when using. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of "Please let me know. Thank you." it would have been more appropriate to have an actual interrogative sentence in your post so we know what question you want answered. E.g. "How can I have a program sent the Ctrl+C, so I don't have to type that myself?"

Comment: @Anthon is that more along the lines of questioning? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that you were trying to use the same VPN transport subnet as you're using for the client LAN.

> ```
> Sat Aug 12 21:57:12 2017 WARNING: potential conflict between --remote address [10.8.0.1] and --ifconfig address pair [10.8.0.6, 10.8.0.5] -- 
> this is a warning only that is triggered when local/remote addresses exist within the same /24 subnet as --ifconfig endpoints.
> ```

Coupling this mistake with the instruction in the server configuration to route all outbound traffic across the VPN tunnel, it's unsurprising you lost internet access while the tunnel was up.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today and after an hour of googling about the problem i solved it by editing `/proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6` file

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
1
```

solved it by

```
$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
```